# NSXMLParser failed in iOS 6 with NSXMLParserErrorDomain=68

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I am facing parsing failed issue in iOS 6 and above only. The code is working in previous version of iOS 6, but not woking in iOS 6 and above. I am trying to send login request to server url. I am getting the response from server in xml format. I am using `NSXMLParser` to parse the response. I am able to parse the xml in iOS 4.x and iOS 5.x but parsing is failed in iOS 6 and above.

```
I am using these lines.

<blink>
NSXMLParser *myparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc initWithData:urlData];
[myParser setDelegate:self];
BOOL flag = [myparser parse];// failing in iOS6 and above.
```

In iOS 6 only `- (void)parse:(NSXMLParser *)parse parseErrorOccoured:(NSError*)parseError` is called.

The error I am getting is `NSXMLParseErrorDomain error 68`.

Comment: could you share the xml response from server.

Comment: Googling your query returned this search result - http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2011/01/nsxmlparsererrordomain-error-68.html

Answer (score 0):

`NSXMLParseErrorDomain` error 68 may be any kind of parsing error. Most probably error in your xml.

```
 -(void)parse:(NSXMLParser )parse parseErrorOccoured:(NSError)parseError
```

will not called in ios 6+ versions I think , thats why you think working perfect in ios6+ devices.

Possible solution is double check the XML and make sure its correct. Then check in case of iOS 6+ devices once more